# UK config for SPA232D

Tags: pbx

I have recently acquired a SPA232D to integrate some VoIP to a system using asterisk. Clearly, it needs to be configured for UK (as distinct from US, AU, other European etc) telco's. There's are some hints out there for the SPA3102, but this one has a different menu setup and some different  options.

However, incoming calls (PSTN to SPA to asterisk to handset) are not routed from the SPA232 to asterisk. Outgoing calls from handset to asterisk to SPA232 to PSTN work fine. Using the information [here](http://www.aoakley.com/articles/2008-01-08.php) and elsewhere, I have set:

*Localisation settings:*

```
Network Setup > Time Settings
    Time Zone: GMT (England)
Voice > Regional > Call Progress Tones
    Dial tone: 350@-19,440@-22;10(*/0/1+2) 
    Ring back: 400@-20,450@-20;*(.4/.2/1+2,.4/2/1+2) 
    Busy tone: 400@-20;10(.375/.375/1) 
    Reorder tone: 400@-20;10(*/0/1) 
    SIT 1 tone: 950@-16,1400@-16,1800@-16;20(.330/0/1,.330/0/2,.330/0/3,0/1/0) 
    MWI dial tone: 350@-19,440@-22;10(.75/.75/1+2) 
Voice > Regional > Distinctive Call Waiting Tone Patterns
    CWT1 cadence: 30(.1/2) 
    CWT2 cadence: 30(.25/.25,.25/.25,.25/5) 
    CWT frequency: 400@-10
Voice > Regional > Distinctive Ring Patterns
    Ring 1 cadence: 60(.4/.2,.4/2) 
    Ring 2 cadence: 60(1/2) 
    Ring 3 cadence: 60(.25/.25,.25/.25,.25/1.75) 
    Ring 4 cadence: 60(.4/.8) 
    Ring 5 cadence: 60(2/4)
Voice > Regional > Miscellaneous
    FXS Port Impedance: 370+620||310nF (or 270+750||150nF ) 
    Caller ID Method: ETSI FSK With PR(UK)
Voice > PSTN > PSTN Disconnect Detection
    Detect CPC: yes 
    Detect Polarity Reversal: no 
    Detect PSTN Long Silence: no 
    PSTN Long Silence Duration: 30 
    PSTN Silence Threshold - High 
    Min CPC Duration: 0.09 
    Detect Disconnect Tone: yes 
    Disconnect Tone - 400@-30,400@-30; 2(3/0/1+2)
Voice > PSTN > International Settings
    Ring Validation Time: 256ms 
    Ring Indication Delay: 512ms 
    Ring Timeout: 640ms
```

I have also set:

```
Voice > PSTN > International Settings
    FXO Country settings: UK
```

I couldn't set because it's not in the menus (I am set up as a bridge):

```
SPA3102 > Advanced > Voice > Regional
    Daylight Saving Rule: start=3/-1/7/1:0:0;end=10/-1/7/2:0:0;save=1:0:0
SPA3102 > Advanced > International Control
    FXO Port Impedance: 270+750||150nF 
    OnHook Speed: 3ms (ETSI) 
    Current Limiting Enable: yes
```

*SIP settings:*

```
Voice > PSTN > Proxy and Registration
   192.168.1.XXX
Voice > PSTN > Subscriber Information
    Display Name: PSTN
    User ID: <username set on asterisk>
    Password: <password set on asterisk>
Voice > PSTN > Dial PLans
    Dial Plan 2: S0(<:@gw0>)
Voice > PSTN > PSTN-To-VoIP Gateway Setup
    PSTN-To-VoIP Gateway Enable: Yes
    PSTN Ring Thru: Yes <Tried both Yes and No, neither worked>
    PSTN CID For VoIP CID: Yes
    PSTN Caller Default DP: 2
    Off Hook While Calling VoIP: No <Tried both Yes and No, neither worked>
```

To save asking: I have checked the asterisk logs and the there is no connection from the SPA to the asterisk server, so it's no a failed authentication issue.

Comment: Are you trying to configure the summer time rule on this device, or get your VoIP server to route calls to it? If the latter, then all of this is irrelevant, and it's the VoIP server (which you've provided no information about at all) that we need to be examining.

Comment: I'm notn interested in the summer time, I'm just trying to provide a complete piece of information. The VoIP server routes calls to teh SPA232 fine - as I note those call go from hanset to VoIP to SPA to PSTN fine. Incoming call from the PSTN to the SPA don't get passed the SPA. I have configured the SIP settings for this, I will add them to the question.

Comment: From your description it sounds like "the VoIP server" is routing calls _from_ the device correctly, not calls _to_ the device. As for the hidden configuration directives, I use XML configuration, which exposes everything.

Comment: Hopefully the question is clear now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much hunting around, it returns out that there is another setting necessary for UK localisation (as I suspected). If you don't set the CID standard (as opposed to method, which I had set correctly) to the right one then the SPA232 will not route the call. Presumably having the wrong CID method means it doesn't realise there is a call. The setting is here:

```
Voice > Regional > Miscellaneous
    Caller ID FSK Standard: v.23
```

For those who would like a full list of the all the UK settings I think that this is a full set. I have used [here](http://blog.pathennessy.org/2009/01/01/configuring-linksys-spa-3102-for-asterisk/), [here](http://www.aoakley.com/articles/2008-01-08.php), [here](https://www.provu.co.uk/pdf/sipura/sipura_uk_regional_settings.pdf) and [here](https://www.ukvoipforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=146). However, if you know of more good references or necessary settings than please add them to the comments add I'll add them to this list.

The odds are that the first thing you will set up is the network side. The Daylight Savings Rule is a little elusive, I think it may have dissappeared in the latest firmware. So, before doing anything that might hide it, if you can, set:

```
Network Setup > Time Settings
    Daylight Saving Rule: start=3/-1/7/1:0:0;end=10/-1/7/2:0:0;save=1:0:0
```

Then complete your network setup. The rest of the UK settings:

```
Network Setup > Time Settings
    Time Zone: GMT (England)
    Adjust Clock for Daylight Saving Changes: Yes
    Timer Server: Auto
Voice > Regional > Call Progress Tones
    Dial tone: 350@-19,440@-22;10(*/0/1+2) 
    Ring back: 400@-20,450@-20;*(.4/.2/1+2,.4/2/1+2) 
    Busy tone: 400@-20;10(.375/.375/1) 
    Reorder tone: 400@-20;10(*/0/1)
    Off Hook Warning Tone: 480@-10,620@-16,1400@0,2060@0,2450@0,2600@0;60(.2/0/1,.2/0/2);240(.1/.1/3+4+5+6)
    SIT 1 tone: 950@-16,1400@-16,1800@-16;20(.330/0/1,.330/0/2,.330/0/3,0/1/0) 
    MWI dial tone: 350@-19,440@-22;10(.75/.75/1+2) 
Voice > Regional > Distinctive Ring Patterns
    Ring 1 cadence: 60(.4/.2,.4/2) 
    Ring 2 cadence: 60(1/2) 
    Ring 3 cadence: 60(.25/.25,.25/.25,.25/1.75) 
    Ring 4 cadence: 60(.4/.8) 
    Ring 5 cadence: 60(2/4)
Voice > Regional > Distinctive Call Waiting Tone Patterns
    CWT1 cadence: 30(.1/2) 
    CWT2 cadence: 30(.25/.25,.25/.25,.25/5)
Voice > Regional > Ring and Call Waiting Tone Spec
    Ring Frequency: 25
    Ring Voltage: 70
    CWT frequency: 400@-10
Voice > Regional > Control Timer Values (sec)
    Hook Flash Timer Min: .06
    Hook Flash Timer Max: .2
    Interdigit Long Timer: 6
    CPC Duration: .09
Voice > Regional > Miscellaneous
    FXS Port Impedance: 370+620||310nF (or 270+750||150nF )
    FXS Port Input Gain: 0
    FXS Port Output Gain: 0
    Caller ID Method: ETSI FSK With PR(UK)
    Caller ID FSK Standard: v.23
Voice > PSTN > PSTN Disconnect Detection
    Detect CPC: yes 
    Detect Polarity Reversal: no 
    Detect PSTN Long Silence: yes
    PSTN Long Silence Duration: 30 
    PSTN Silence Threshold - High 
    Min CPC Duration: 0.09 
    Detect Disconnect Tone: yes 
    Disconnect Tone: 400@-30,400@-30; 2(3/0/1+2)
Voice > PSTN > International Settings
    FXO Country settings: UK
    Ring Validation Time: 256ms 
    Ring Indication Delay: 512ms 
    Ring Timeout: 640ms
```

As @James points out below, be sure to set the ports carefully as well!

Answer (score 1):

I will add one thing to this, and that is that if you're using Asterisk 13 or above where `chan_PJSIP` is the default driver (listening on port 5060) and `chan_SIP` is the secondary driver (listening on port 5061), then your `PSTN proxy`, AND your `PSTN Dial plan` MUST include `:5061` in the address in order to ensure the call is handled by the chan_SIP driver, otherwise you will just see alot of errors along the line of
`NOTICE[9428] res_pjsip/pjsip_distributor.c: Request from '"PSTN" <sip:PSTN@192.168.1.5>' failed for '192.168.1.24:5061' (callid: 7746ed92-88802db0@192.168.1.24) - No matching endpoint found`

to this effect, your config should look like this:

```
Voice > PSTN > Proxy and Registration
   192.168.1.XXX:5061
Voice > PSTN > Dial PLans
   Dial Plan 2: S0(<:N@gw0:5061>)
```

where `N` can be anything you like, and will be passed to asterisk as the DID